# SSRS BIDS 2008 Expression

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, expression

What is the correct expression to use for todays date plus 1 year.

I assume it starts with Now()+ but im unsure from there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157328.aspx#VisualBasicFunctions) has lots of great examples, including:

```
=DateAdd(DateInterval.Month, 6, Parameters!StartDate.Value)
```

From that and the example before it, it looks like you want:

```
=DateAdd(DateInterval.Year, 1, Today())
```

Answer (score 0):

this should be what your looking for:

--midnight last day of last month

select DateAdd(mm,-0,(DATEADD(s,-1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,GETDATE()),0))))

--midnight last day of this month

select DateAdd(mm,+1,(DATEADD(s,-1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,GETDATE()),0))))

--midnight last day of last month 1 year ago

select DateAdd(yy,-1,(DATEADD(s,-1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,GETDATE()),0))))

--midnight last day of this month 1 year ago

select DateAdd(yy,-1,DateAdd(mm,+1,(DATEADD(s,-1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,GETDATE()),0)))))